# How to use grouping sets in this query that shows database sizes - adding the last time it was updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query, group-by, automation

I have the following query that shows me the database sizes, including `log` dna `data` files.

```
SELECT [Database Name] = DB_NAME(s.database_id),

       [Type] = CASE WHEN s.Type_Desc = 'ROWS' THEN 'Data File(s)'

                     WHEN s.Type_Desc = 'LOG'  THEN 'Log File(s)'

                     ELSE s.Type_Desc END,

     --  LastUpdate= (select COALESCE(max(last_user_update),MAX(last_system_update)) 
        --             from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats dius 
                    --where dius.database_id = s.database_id),

       [Size in MB] = CAST( ((SUM(s.Size)* 8) / 1024.00) AS DECIMAL(18,2) ),
       [Size in GB] = CAST( ((SUM(s.Size)* 8) / 1024.00/1024.00) AS DECIMAL(18,2) )

FROM   sys.master_files s
-- Uncomment if you need to query for a particular database
-- WHERE      database_id = DB_ID(‘Database Name’)

GROUP BY      GROUPING SETS

              (

                     (DB_NAME(s.database_id), s.Type_Desc),

                     (DB_NAME(s.database_id))

                     --(DB_NAME(s.database_id),s.database_id)

              )

ORDER BY      DB_NAME(s.database_id), s.Type_Desc DESC

GO
```

and that gives me the following picture in one of my test servers:

[image]

I would like to add the `last time the database was updated` to the results of my query, as you can see on the `commented lines in the query above`, but that is giving me the following result set:

```
SELECT [Database Name] = DB_NAME(s.database_id),

       [Type] = CASE WHEN s.Type_Desc = 'ROWS' THEN 'Data File(s)'

                     WHEN s.Type_Desc = 'LOG'  THEN 'Log File(s)'

                     ELSE s.Type_Desc END,

       LastUpdate= (select COALESCE(max(last_user_update),MAX(last_system_update)) 
                     from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats dius 
                    where dius.database_id = s.database_id),

       [Size in MB] = CAST( ((SUM(s.Size)* 8) / 1024.00) AS DECIMAL(18,2) ),
       [Size in GB] = CAST( ((SUM(s.Size)* 8) / 1024.00/1024.00) AS DECIMAL(18,2) )

FROM   sys.master_files s
-- Uncomment if you need to query for a particular database
-- WHERE      database_id = DB_ID(‘Database Name’)

GROUP BY      GROUPING SETS

              (

                     (DB_NAME(s.database_id), s.Type_Desc),

                     (DB_NAME(s.database_id)),

                     (DB_NAME(s.database_id),s.database_id)

              )

ORDER BY      DB_NAME(s.database_id), s.Type_Desc DESC

GO
```

[image]

How can I change my query to display the `last time the database was updated`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just removed the `DB_Name` from `Grouping`

```
SELECT [Database Name] = DB_NAME(s.database_id),
       [Type] = CASE WHEN s.Type_Desc = 'ROWS' THEN 'Data File(s)'
                     WHEN s.Type_Desc = 'LOG'  THEN 'Log File(s)'
                     ELSE s.Type_Desc END,

       LastUpdate= case when s.type_desc ='ROWS' then NULL
                       when s.type_desc = 'LOG' then NULL
                       else        
                           (select COALESCE(max(last_user_update),MAX(last_system_update)) 
                                         from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats dius 
                                        where dius.database_id = s.database_id)
                    end,
       [Size in MB] = CAST( ((SUM(s.Size)* 8) / 1024.00) AS DECIMAL(18,2) ),
       [Size in GB] = CAST( ((SUM(s.Size)* 8) / 1024.00/1024.00) AS DECIMAL(18,2) )

FROM   sys.master_files s
GROUP BY      GROUPING SETS
              (
                     (s.database_id, s.Type_Desc),
                     (s.database_id)
              )
ORDER BY      DB_NAME(s.database_id), s.Type_Desc DESC
```

output:

```
Database Name   Type         lastUpdate  Size in MB Size in GB  
db_xxx          Log File(s)   Null            8.00     0.01      
db_xxx          Data File(s)  Null            8.00     0.01      
db_xxx          NULL          2019-07-14 17:27:04.473  16.00       0.02
```